# My app runs fine but the TextView won't show up

Tags: java, android

I'm making this front page of my app. Unfortunately, only the `TextView` won't show. The button and the background run just fine. I have even added it to the relative layout but using the `addView()` function. Can someone please help?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //layout
    RelativeLayout mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    //button
    Button mainButton = new Button (this);
    mainButton.setText("Next");
    mainButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    //textview
    TextView mainTextView = new TextView(this);
    mainTextView.setText("Juliet Daniel Lab Molecular Biology Cancer Research Center");
    mainTextView.setTextSize(30);
    mainTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    //sizing the button
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btnDetails = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    //sizing the textview
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textViewDetails = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    //give id's to position relatively...note it is preferable to do this in the res folder to avoid errors
    mainButton.setId(1);
    mainTextView.setId(2);

    //give rules to position widgets relatively
    textViewDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, mainButton.getId());
    textViewDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    textViewDetails.setMargins(0,0,0,50);


    //adding the button as a part of the RelativeLayout (ADDING THE BUTTON WIDGET TO LAYOUT)
    mainLayout.addView(mainButton, btnDetails);
    //adding the textview as a part of the relative Layout
    mainLayout.addView(mainTextView, textViewDetails);

    //setting the view as out layour
    setContentView(mainLayout);

}
}
```

Comment: Try Munir's answer. Just a suggestion rather than setting the ids as 1,2 use View.generateviewid() method to setId

Comment: You're aligning your `mainTextView` *above* your `mainButton`--which is the main problem. You should use layout parameter rules of `mainButton` with respect to the `mainTextView`; not the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you set `textview` above button where the `button` is first top of root layout that's why it's not showing try to set `textview` below button and it's work

```
textViewDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, mainButton.getId());
```

Comment: Thank you!! It's working. Can you please tag a link here for me to read and understand this issue thoroughly?

Comment: Link for what ?